# How to find the top right and bottom left vertexes of a polygon?

Tags: polygons

Having the coordinates of polygon vertexes, what is the formula to find the top right and bottom left vertexes?

Also, how is top right and bottom left vertex of a polygon defined?

Comment: There is no formula, but there is a simple algorithm.

Comment: what algorithm is it?

Comment: Also, which of these vertices (A, B, C, D) would you consider the top right or bottom left? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tva3w.png

Comment: @PrestonMillward i don't know, i was asking that too

Comment: I just found this site, I think it will give us both an answer. http://geomalgorithms.com/a14-_extreme_pts.html

Comment: thanks. the binary search algorithm is a little bit hard for me, though. what did you get when running it for your example?